# createEntityManagerFactory and netbuddy problem

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, hibernate-entitymanager

I've got a problem with `netbuddy` and `createEntityManagerFactory` function. I tried to reinstall maven, add `netbuddy` dependency but it doesn't help.

**The error:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/NamingStrategy$SuffixingRandom$BaseNameResolver at 
...
bd2app/bd2app.dao.UzytkownicyDao.<init>(UzytkownicyDao.java:11)
```

**Persistence.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="Entities">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>bd2app.model.InstruktorzyEntity</class>
        <class>bd2app.model.InstruktorzyKategoriaEntity</class>
        <class>bd2app.model.KategoriaEntity</class>
        <class>bd2app.model.RezerwacjeEntity</class>
        <class>bd2app.model.TransakcjeEntity</class>
        <class>bd2app.model.UslugiEntity</class>
        <class>bd2app.model.UzytkownicyEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://mateuszsliwka.pl:3306/mateuszs_projekt"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="mateuszs_projekt"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**UzytkownicyDao.java**

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import java.util.List;

public class UzytkownicyDao implements Dao<UzytkownicyEntity> {
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Entities");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    @Override
    public void persist(UzytkownicyEntity entity) {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

**Dependencies:**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.18</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Important info - on my PC everything works fine, on my MacBook and my friends PC does not!**

Comment: Looks like incompatible jar files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)